# Plot of count data from table

Tags: r, csv, plot

I have a CSV file containing approximately 2000 data points (counts) for each of 10 samples:

```
3,1,3,2,2,2,0,...
2,0,0,1,3,2,1,...
3,0,3,0,3,1,0,...
....
```

I used the following to view the tabulated counts for each sample:

```
x = read.csv('thefile.csv', header=FALSE)
table(as.numeric(x[1,])
table(as.numeric(x[2,])
table(as.numeric(x[3,])
```

I would like to plot a bar (or other) graph of the tabulated counts for all samples, to compare them. When I tried to do that as a test with the first five samples:

```
a = table(as.numeric(x[1,])
b = table(as.numeric(x[2,])
c = ...
barplot(rbind(a,b,c,d,e))
```

I found that the values in the graph were misaligned, because not all samples had the same count values. The value of "1" may be absent in sample 2, for example, resulting in no matching entry in the tabulated results.

What is the best way to plot these tabulated count data to compare them visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible data:

```
x <- replicate(10, round(10 * rexp(2000, 10)))
```

As you rightly note, the frequency table for each sample may not contain all the values.

```
apply(x, 2, table)
## [[1]]

##   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   8 
## 771 798 274 104  37  14   1   1 

## [[2]]

##   0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
## 792 788 275  77  37  26   5    

## etc.
```

The trick is to convert each column of `x` to be a factor with all possible values of x as its levels.

```
(y <- apply(x, 2, function(column) table(factor(column, levels = 0:9))))
##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## 0  771  792  797  783  775  806  801  793  788   795
## 1  798  788  795  744  792  738  765  720  729   760
## 2  274  275  253  308  271  288  263  297  312   261
## 3  104   77   91  110  104  114  103  117  106   124
## 4   37   37   42   37   35   33   48   49   41    36
## 5   14   26   16    8   11   16   12   15   17    14
## 6    1    5    3    8    8    2    3    4    6     7
## 7    0    0    3    1    3    3    2    1    1     1
## 8    1    0    0    1    1    0    3    3    0     1
## 9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
```

Then you can draw your barplot

```
barplot(y)
```